# How to reset the variables of an object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to reset the following objects inside a

```
draw = function() {...}

var Beaver = function(x, y) {    
    this.x = x;   
    this.y = y;   
    this.img = getImage("");   
    this.sticks = 0;   
    this.holes = 0;   
    this.npcs = 0;   
};
var Stick = function(x, y) {    
    this.x = x;    
    this.y = y;    
};
var Hole = function(x, y) {   
    this.x = x;   
    this.y = y;   
};
var Npc = function(x, y) {    
    this.x = x;    
    this.y = y;    
    this.img = getImage("");    
};
```

How to do that?

Comment: instantiate new objecst with the constructor functions - passed as parameters to to `draw()`.

Comment: set `x` and `y` to initial values?

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"?

Comment: I am coding a game and when the level 1 ends , the level 2 continues from the same spot(beaver, sticks, holes) and doesnt restart.